# NavigationServices.Navigate not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Hi I am new to Windows Phone Development may be I am doing a bit awkward stuff while writing the code, can I do the stuff like

```
button_click()
{
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HttpHandler.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            WebHandler.Make_url_HandleResponse("someurl", 1);  
}

/*In HttpHandler Class having object Webhandler in previous class*/
     public void Make_url_HandleResponse(string Uri, int req_id)
        {
            try
            {
                uri = new Uri(Uri);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            }

       request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri);


            Debug.WriteLine("The url is" + uri);


        }



public void request_CallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            //var request = (HttpWebRequest) result.AsyncState; 
            Stream stream;
            string ext_str;
            char[] separator = { '/' };

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

            using (stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {

               /* here I want to navigate to a new page*/
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                             downloadingProgress.IsIndeterminate = false;
                             downloadingProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                            stkDownloading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewUser.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            { }
                        }); 
    }
```

all I am trying to ask whether I can navigate to another page from httphandler page. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think your question is quite clear? Why can't you Navigate away from this page?

You can Navigate away from any page.

Comment: @Hi Carl, Le me explain it in more clear way I am successfully navigating to the page "HttpHandler.xaml" but as soon as I am trying to navigate to after handling http response to "NewUser.xaml " I am getting nullpointer exception I am unable to find out the reason behind. I have MainPage.xaml where on buttonclick from where user can login and httphandler class will show the loading screen and after handling the http response it will navigate to newuser.xaml page

Comment: I ran your code but there is no error in the navigation part. If your namespaces are correct the only issue could be a null pointer in the constructor of NewUser or an error with downloadingProgress. 

Where is the exception coming? 
Can you post a bit of the debug?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the namespace of both the pages are same (source & target pages) otherwise you have to mention the path in uri string. Code for navigating to another screen is same:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pageNmae.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: Hi Deepak I have checked all the namespaces all are same for the pages I am getting nullpointer excpetion while navigating to the NewUser.xaml after receiving http response.